# VS Code auto imports console when I use console.log

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When I try to use console.log, VS Code automatically imports console module at the top of the file.

```
import console = require('console');
```

How can I stop this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vscode imports import console = require("console"); automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279182/vscode-imports-import-console-requireconsole-automatically)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279182/vscode-imports-import-console-requireconsole-automatically