# vscode automatically imported import * as console from 'console'

Tags: import, autocomplete, console, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio code editor, I have used console.log from auto suggestion. If I hit enter on a auto suggested console.log, vscode automatically imports console to the ts.file. How do I remove auto import of console?

Comment: Can You check the Discussion here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279182/vscode-imports-import-console-requireconsole-automatically

Comment: I have seen this before, There they are asking to click on require("console"). But in my case I don't have this kind of statements, so I'm not able to relate. @tHeSiD